# Check online connection with SQL server, switch to offline C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# Windows app that I am creating with connection to a MS SQL server.  I need the ability to switch to a local instance of SQL Server express if connectivity is down. This app is in a remote area where online is hit and miss. When connectivity goes down, I need the connection strings to reflect to the local server. I have logic to resync items from the local db to the live one once connection is restored. However, I am having issues trying to test connectivity automatically.  The connection string in my `app.config` has both live and offline connections with the following code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyLiveConnectionString);
```

If connection goes down, I want the local connection to use:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyLocalConnectionString);
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make this happen seamlessly and quick?

I can test connections using `try`/`catch`, but it takes several seconds to time out before continuing.

Comment: Always use the local one and let your resync items logic do the work. You will have less use case scenario this way and you'll be less likely to hit some weird case that haven't been tested.

Comment: That's a good idea.   I will look into doing that and then have some automated process upload every minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Connect()
{
    string connectionStr = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if(CheckConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyLiveConnectionString))
            connectionStr = Properties.Settings.Default.MyLiveConnectionString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log this, etc...
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionStr))
        connectionStr = Properties.Settings.Default.MyLocalConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {

    }
}

private static bool CheckConnection(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1", conn);
        conn.Open();
        if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I will check it out.